# Having conditional rendering on an id of div tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Currently I'm trying to move my image from center to left and left to right as the user scrolls down. For achieving this, I'm using useEffect to manipulate my DOM events. I want the layout in such a way that after the user has scrolled 600 pixels in height the image starts moving to the right. For this I tried conditionally rendering a div tag but I get an error in my useEffect since it doesnt recognize the other element. So how can I move my image when it reaches a certain height?

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sun-e6odq?file=/src/App.js

Code:

```
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  useEffect(function onFirstMount() {
    const changeBackground = () => {
      let value = window.scrollY;
      console.log(value);
      let img = document.getElementById("moveLeft");
      let img2 = document.getElementById("moveRight");

      img.style.transform = `translateX(-${value * 0.5}px)`;
      img2.style.transform = `translateX(${value * 0.5}px)`;

      if (value > 600) {
        setDisplay(true);
      } else {
        setDisplay(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div class="inflow">
          <div class="positioner">
            <div class="fixed">
              <div id={display?"moveRight":"moveLeft"}>
                <img
                  alt="passport"
                  src="https://cdn.britannica.com/87/122087-050-1C269E8D/Cover-passport.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="App2">
      </div>
      <div className="App2"></div>
    </>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two calls to getElementById and you dynamically change the id based on state, you will always have an undefined element.

You could fix it like so

```
  let img =
    document.getElementById("moveLeft") ||
    document.getElementById("moveRight");
  const val = img.id === "moveLeft" ? -(value * 0.5) : value * 0.5;
  img.style.transform = `translateX(${val}px)`;
```

And remove the img2 call, as there is always one of the above in the document. Example of this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-babycat-6bl5i?file=/src/App.js

You could also try to achieve it with only one image:

```
  useEffect(
    function onFirstMount() {
      const changeBackground = () => {
        if (!imgRef || !imgRef.current) return;

        const value = window.scrollY;

        if (value > 600) {
          imgRef.current.style.display = `block`;
        } else {
          imgRef.current.style.display = `none`;
          return;
        }

        const progress = (window.innerWidth / 100) * moveRatio;

        if (
          animData.current.isGoingRight &&
          animData.current.currentPos >= window.innerWidth - 200
        ) {
          animData.current.isGoingRight = false;
        } else if (
          !animData.current.isGoingRight &&
          animData.current.currentPos <= startPosition
        ) {
          animData.current.isGoingRight = true;
        }

        if (animData.current.isGoingRight)
          animData.current.currentPos += progress;
        else animData.current.currentPos -= progress;

        imgRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${animData.current.currentPos}px)`;
      };
      window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);
    },
    [imgRef]
  );
```

This one moves in relation to the window inner width, you can see it here https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-microservice-xb2ku?file=/src/App.js, that's just an example, I'm sure there are another approaches